# How to use Array.map with typescript generic parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

So I have this function, that will process array of data the same way, dump it all on database. The code:

```js
type DataOne = {
    id: number,
    nano: string;
}

type DataTwo = {
    id: number,
    nanz: string;
    tap: string,
}

type GetTar = DataOne | DataTwo

function saveToDB<K = GetTar>(items: K[]): boolean {
    const ids = items.map(item => item.id)
    // ...
    // More just imaginecode to save to database and return true
    // ...
    return ids.length > 0
}

const dataOnes: DataOne[] = [
    { id: 1, nano: '12312' }
]

saveToDB<DataOne>(dataOnes)
```

It has the same key `id` but the other one aren't.

I want the function can only be used with data from type `DataOne` and `DataTwo` nothing else. So I create generic for it. How ever it have an error `Property 'id' does not exist on type 'K'.(2339)` since the map doesn't know what data it dealing at it return that error.

How do I create the right type generic for this kind of problem?

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOB5AdtAvFA3gKCvqASwBMAuKFAVwFsAjCAJwBo8CU4UB7cgZ2AcIoA5gG4cAXxw5QkWAjgAVAO6comXASJkKNes1b52KAF69+g0QaiIwZgcJaTp4aAHEIwBXAZq5iVNAAPn6KKlIAZpQoAMbAhJwoUDxwAG4QCpwwAEIAPADSvu6e3gB8ABSEwBDUPOR5ANoAugCU5LScnAA2EBzYVtEJfFo8vpXVPAB01HBgFVXUaiVE8xMkzVYMHpQMiSST3cLAABZQSwAMElIDKEPE8gG1IQFNvvVWWFrkAIxMFBzcUAA5F8AEwAZlBgKgkkaUmSaQy2Ry8H8aHKd1REB4zSAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know `K` is `GetTar` so there is no need to generic function:

```
function saveToDB(items: GetTar[]): boolean {
    const ids = items.map(item => item.id)
    return ids.length > 0
}
```

But if you want to make it to generic function you need to use `extends`:

```
function saveToDB<K extends GetTar>(items: K[]): boolean {
    const ids = items.map(item => item.id)
    return ids.length > 0
}
```

[PlaygroundLink](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOB5AdtAvFA3gKCvqASwBMAuKFAVwFsAjCAJwBo8CU4UB7cgZ2AcIoA5gG4cAXxw5QkWAjgAVAO6comXASJkKNes1b52KAF69%20g0QaiIwZgcJaTp4aAHEIwBXAZq5iVNAAPn6KKlIAZpQoAMbAhJwoUDxwAG4QCpwwAEIAPADSUBAAHsAQKMQ8UO6e3gB8ABSEpdQ85HkA2gC6AJTktJycADYQHNhW0Ql8WpWYTRAtAHTUcGCNzWq1RM0LJN1WDB6UDIkkPAvDwsAAFlCbAAwSUhMoU8TyAa0hAV2%207VZYWnIAEYmBQONwoAByIEAJgAzLDIVBJJ0pMk0hlsjl4P40A03riIDxukA)